# Django - Looping through two queries for the same data, and adding cost field for each

Tags: python, django

Its likely the title could be worded better but im struggling with it.

Basically i am trying to tally up the cost of circuits per site from my models. the circuit model inherts the site model as per below:

models:

```
class ShowroomConfigData(models.Model):
    location = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class CircuitInfoData(models.Model):    
    showroom_config_data = models.ForeignKey(ShowroomConfigData,verbose_name="Install Showroom")
    major_site_info = models.ForeignKey(MajorSiteInfoData,verbose_name="Install Site") 
    circuit_type = models.CharField(max_length=100,choices=settings.CIRCUIT_CHOICES)    
    circuit_speed = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    cost_per_month = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2,max_digits=8)
```

how this probably could be done with queries, but ive tried in a pervious question and it seems ive hit a bug so im trying to do it manually

sample data:

```
site a | 1
site a | 2
site a | 5
site b | 100
site b | 2
site d | 666
site d | 1
```

so i want to produce

site a | 8
site b | 102
site d | 667

i tried this way as a test:

```
circuits = CircuitInfoData.objects.all()  
showrooms = ShowroomConfigData.objects.only('location')

for sdata in showrooms:
    for cdata in circuits:
        while cdata.showroom_config_data.location == sdata.location:
         print sdata.location
         print cdata.cost
```

this has just churned out the site a and 8 x amount of times. so i dont know how i should be going about this instead?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most efficient way to do this is using queries. This can be accomplished using [annotations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/aggregation/), in the following way:

```
from django.db.models import Sum
CircuitInfoData.objects.values("showroom_config_data__location") \
                       .annotate(cost=Sum("cost_per_month"))
```

E.g. this will return data in the form

```
[{'showroom_config_data__location': u'site a', 'cost': Decimal('30.00')},
 {'showroom_config_data__location': u'site b', 'cost': Decimal('5.00')}]
```

You can then format this output

```
for entry in output:
    print entry["showroom_config_data__location"], " | ", entry["cost"]
```

To get

```
site a | 30.00
site b | 5.00
```

Comment: hi this returns site a | 1, site a | 12, site a | 3 and so on, its not summing up where the location is the same...

Comment: fixed, i had this in the model that was causing all sorts of issues ordering = ('showroom_config_data__location','circuit_speed')

Answer (score 0):

What if you just used a dictionary?  Each circuit will have access to the showroom right?  So If you built a dictionary and simply pulled out the value at a particular site if that is already being used as a key, you could simply add the value and store it again.  Here is an example of this being done.

```
my_dictionary = dict()
for circuit in circuits:
     if my_dictionary[circuit.showroom_config_data.location] in my_dictionary:
          my_dictionary[circuit.showroom_config_data.location] += circuit.cost_per_month
     else:
          my_dictionary[circuit.showroom_config_data.location] = circuit.cost_per_month
```

May not work exactly but the concept behind the code will give you the desired output you are looking for.